# Errors from If statements?

Tags: batch-file, if-statement

I have a 456 line batch file, and close to the end it is stuffing up on if statements comparing variables on all of the following

```
if "%user%" EQU "%temp%"
if %user% EQU %temp%
if %user% == %temp%
if "%user%" == "%temp%"
if %user% == 0
if "%user%" == "0"
if %user% EQU 0
if "%user%" EQU "0"
```

It comes up with an error saying

> The syntax of the command is incorrect

(temp is always equal to 0, and user is equal to 2, 1, or 0)

The syntax error occurs if the first 2 lines don't have `echo ...` at the end of them

```
if "%enemy%" == "%temp%"( echo ...
  if NOT '%choice%'=='1'( echo ...
    if %enemyat% GTR %resistance% ( 
      set /a health-=1
      set /a resistance=16+8*%resistancelvl%
    ) else ( 
      set /a resistance-=%enemyat%
    )
  )
)
```

Comment: Which is the line 456 here? Have you tried to isolate the problem by making a separate batch file with the failing code?

Comment: They're all the same line, just none of them have worked, im trying that now

Answer (score 2):

You're missing a space before the `(` on the first two lines.

```
if "%enemy%"=="%temp%" ( 
    if NOT '%choice%'=='1' ( 
        if %enemyat% GTR %resistance% ( 
            set /a health-=1
            set /a resistance=16+8*%resistancelvl%
        ) else ( 
            set /a resistance-=%enemyat%
        )
    )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

<strike>Try `if %user%==0`or `if %user%==%temp%`.</strike>

Notice the lack of spacing between the '==' and the variables.

Comment: Spaces don't matter when the variable is surrounded by quotes.